# What library am I missing if Google.Api.AnnotationsReflection is missing from my gRPC project?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, grpc

I built some protocal buffers using Protoc tools version 1.7.2 using the project I created from followed the tutorial here:
https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/csharp.html#update-and-run-the-application

The code generated from the .proto file spat out this line:
    new pbr::FileDescriptor[] { global::Google.Api.AnnotationsReflection.Descriptor, },

I have tried updating all the nuget dependencies to 1.8.0. Still missing this library. The term is too generic to find anything useful with a web search.

What do I need to include to get this working?

Comment: The problem is not really related to gRPC. It looks like that some of your .proto files are importing "google/api/annotations.proto" (and the descriptor of Google.Api.AnnotationsReflection.Descriptor is generated when annotations.proto gets compiled - have you 1.) forgotten to generate code for annotations.proto  2.) not included the generated c# file for annotations.proto in your project?

Answer (score 4):

Install the package "Google.Api.Gax.Grpc".

From the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio select your project, then run:
Install-Package Google.Api.Gax.Grpc

Answer (score 0):

Installing the nuget package "Google.Api.CommonProtos" works, I believe it's been removed from "Google.Api.Gax.Grpc"